# Calculating inertia for a multi-shape rigid body

Tags: dynamic, physics

I figured someone probably asked this question before but I wasn't able to find an answer.

I'm writing a physics library for my game engine (2d, currently in actionscript3, but easily translatable to C based languages).

I'm having problems finding a good formula to calculate the inertia of my game objects.

The thing is, there are plenty of proven formulas to calculate inertia around a centroid of a convex polygon, but my structure is slightly different: I have game-objects with their own local space. You can add convex shapes such as circles and convex polygons to this local space to form complex objects. The shapes themselves again have their own local space. So there are three layers: World, object & shape space.

I would have no problems calculating the inertia of each individual polygon in the shape with the formulas provided on the [moments of inertia Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia).

or the ones provided in an awesome [collision detection & response article](http://elancev.name/oliver/2D%20polygon.htm#tut7).

But I'm wondering how to relate this to my object structure, do I simply add all the inertia's of the shapes of the object? That's what another writer uses to [calculate the inertia of triangulated polygons](http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=57), he adds all the moments of inertia of the triangles. Or is there more to it?

I find this whole inertia concept quite difficult to understand as I don't have a strong physics background. So if anyone could provide me with an answer, preferably with the logic behind inertia around a given centroid, I would be very thankful. I actually study I.T. - Game development at my university, but to my great frustration none of the teachers in their ranks are experienced in the area of physics.

Comment: @cha - I think you might want to read the [W3C guidance on link text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#link-text).

Comment: @Flexo I didn't get you .... please clarify

Answer (score 3):

Laurens, the physics is much simpler if you stay in two dimensional space. In 2D space, rotations are described by a scalar, resistance to rotation (moment of inertia) is described by a scalar, and rotations are additive and commutative. Things get hairy (much, much hairier) in three dimensional space.

When you connect two objects, the combined object has its own center of mass. To calculate the moment of inertia of this combined object, you need to sum the moments of inertia of the individual objects and also add on offset term given by the [Steiner parallel axis theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) for each individual object. This offset term is the mass of the object times the square of the distance to the composite center of mass.

The primary reason you need to know the moment of inertia is so that you can simulate the response to torques that act on your object. This is fairly straightforward in 2D physics. Rotational behavior is an analog to Newton's second law. Instead of F=ma you use T=Iα. (Things once again are much hairier in 3D space.) You need to find the external forces and torques, solve for linear acceleration and rotational acceleration, and then integrate numerically.

A good beginner's book on game physics is probably in order. You can find a list of recommended texts in [this question at the gamedev sister site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16362/what-is-a-good-book-on-physics-for-game-development).

Comment: Ahh ok, so the writer of the article in the final link of my post was correct. Didn't know about the term "parallel axis theorem", thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I understand why I need the moment of inertia, but wasn't sure on how to calculate it. Is it normal for the value of inertia to be really big? I used the way of calculating it like you described, but thats giving me huge numbers. if I test it for an object made up of one square shaped polygon with a width and height of 80, placed with its center at the center of the object, the inertia that pops out is: 3413333.3333333335. I calculate my object mass from the area of the object times a density scalar thats currently set to one. Is this a normal result? It just seems like a huge number.

Comment: O and thanks for that list of physics books, you're right I could really use one. My collision responce code is giving me terribly faulty results at the moment

Comment: @Laurens - Re your value of 3413333 for a square of width=height=80, density=1: That number looks about half what it should be. The mass moment of inertia of a rectangular plate through the center of the plate is m*(h^2+w^2)/12. With mass m=ρ*h*w, this becomes ρ*h*w*(h^2+w^2)/12. Setting ρ=1, h=w yields I=w^4/6. Mass moments of inertia in 2D land often grow by the fourth power, so the numbers get big fast.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out again, your answers have been really clear and usefull. It turned out I made a mistake translating the inertia formula to code. For that same polygon I'm now getting 6826666.666666667, which like you said is twice the result I was getting before. So I think my surface area, mass and inertia calculations are now correct.

Answer (score 0):

For linear motion you can just add them. Inertia is proportional to mass. Adding the masses of your objects and calculating the inertia of the sum is equivalent to adding their individual inertias.

For rotation it gets more complicated, you need to find the centre of mass.

Read up on Newton's laws of motion. You'll need to understand them if you're writing a physics engine. The laws themselves are very short but understanding them requires more context so google around.

You should specifically try to understand the concepts: Mass, Inertia, Force, Acceleration, Momentum, Velocity, Kinetic energy. They're all related.

Comment: -1: No, you can't just add them. Even in 2D land you have to worry about the parallel axis theorem.

Comment: Ah, true. I only considered linear motion. Care to elaborate?

Comment: You have to consider the center of mass offset. Think of what happens when you connect point masses with massless rods. A massless rod has zero mass and hence zero moment of inertia. Point masses have zero moment of inertia about the center of mass, so just adding the moments of inertia of the objects would yield zero. Adding in the parallel axis theorem offsets makes for a composite object with a positive moment of inertia.